# Ajax Get Method Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this javascript code, it must get a list of my viewmodel, but success function is not called, error function is called.
What is my error?

```
var id = 5;
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/ArizaTalep/Get_List?tid=" + id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {  },
        error: function (data) { alert("error!!") }

    });
```

Controller:

```
    public List<DURUM_HAREKET_ViewModel> Get_List(int tid)
    {
        DH_DataModel dmodel = new DH_DataModel();
        var ll = dmodel.GetAll().Where(i => i.T_ID == tid).ToList();
        return ll;
    }
```

Comment: you are not returning JSON Result

Comment: just return jsonresult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Get_List(int tid)
{
  DH_DataModel dmodel = new DH_DataModel();
  var ll = dmodel.GetAll().Where(i => i.T_ID == tid).ToList();
  return Json(ll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your action to:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Get_List(int tid)
{
   DH_DataModel dmodel = new DH_DataModel();
   var ll = dmodel.GetAll().Where(i => i.T_ID == tid).ToList();
   return Json(ll);
}
```

and

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/ArizaTalep/Get_List",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {tid: id},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {  },
        error: function (data) { alert("error!!") }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change Controller to:

```
public ActionResult Get_List(int tid)
{
    DH_DataModel dmodel = new DH_DataModel();
    var ll = dmodel.GetAll().Where(i => i.T_ID == tid).ToList();
    return Json(ll, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Explanation:**
You need to return Json type to get it into your View Success function.

Comment: He does POST in ajax call he does not need JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet